# How can I tell upstart to restart a service when a different service is restarted?

Tags: 12.04, upstart

I've an OpenERP server running on one of my servers.  It's started by a traditional `/etc/init.d/` script.  It uses a PostgreSQL database and needs a manual restart every time PostgreSQL is restarted.

Every time Ubuntu releases a security update for PostgreSQL, my OpenERP server becomes non-functional until I ssh to the server and manually run `sudo /etc/init.d/my-openerp restart`.  I usually forget to do that after I do the `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Can I configure upstart to do that for me, every time postgresql is restarted by apt?

Comment: Will `start on started posgre` and `stop on stopped postgre` work for you? It will start/stop _my-openerp_ always on started/stopped postgre and not only after upgrade. Please not that I don't know what is the exact name of PostgeSQL server Upstart configuration file.

Comment: It would appear that PostgreSQL doesn't have an Upstart file in 12.04, and is instead started by /etc/init.d/postgresql.

Comment: Note to self: https://code.launchpad.net/~florent.x/openobject-server/trunk-bug-905257-fix-reconnect/+merge/132149 aims to fix the actual problem (OpenERP not reconnecting).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the postgresql server is still using deprecated System-V init script there are two options:

- Emit events from the existing System-V init script
- Port existing System-V init script to upstart job

In both cases you can use `start on started-postgresql` and `stop on stopping-postgresql` in your job. As mentioned in the comment  *my-openerp* will start/stop always on started/stopped *postgresql* and not only after upgrade.

If you opt for emitting events from the existing System-V init script you will need to add in /etc/init.d/postgresql:

```
# just before the service is started
initctl emit starting-postgresql
# just after the service is started
initctl emit started-postgresql 
# just before stopping the service
initctl emit stopping-postgresql
# just after the service is stopped
initctl emit stopped-postgresql
```

For details see Helpful Tips in [Writing Services](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto#Writing_Services) section on Ubuntu Boot up Howto page.

In case that you opt for creating Upstart job the simplest configuration might look like this:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]
respawn

exec su -c "/etc/postgresql/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data" postgres
```

More elaborated Upstart config can be found [here](http://bradleyayers.blogspot.com/2011/10/upstart-job-for-postgresql-91-on-ubuntu.html).

I would play around and instead of starting postgresql on runlevel [2345] perhaps say

```
start on filesystem and net-device-up IFACE!=lo
```

or

```
start on started networking
```

You might also consider adding kill timeout stanza

```
kill timeout 300
```

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on [schkovich's](https://askubuntu.com/a/255974/5252) first option, here's a simple modification to the System V `/etc/init.d/postgresql` script.

So whenever postgres is sent "start/restart"/"reload"/"force-restart", I send the "starting-postgresql" event before the command is issued, and the "started-postgresql" after its finished.  Similarly, with "stop", I send the "stopping-postgresql" event before the command and "stopped-postgresql" after its issued.

I'm only showing the final case block (`case "$1" in [...] esac` at the bottom of the script.  To make the changes clearer (in case future versions of postgres modify the system-V script, I've highlighted the lines that need to be inserted by putting them between `#### BEGIN emit-upstart-event` and `#### END emit-upstart-event`.

```
case "$1" in
    start|stop|restart|reload)
        if [ -z "`pg_lsclusters -h`" ]; then
            log_warning_msg 'No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster"'
            exit 0
        fi
        #### BEGIN emit-upstart-event
        case "$1" in
            start|restart|reload)
                initctl emit starting-postgresql
            ;;
            stop)
                initctl emit stopping-postgresql
            ;;
        esac
        #### END emit-upstart-event
        for v in $versions; do
            $1 $v || EXIT=$?
        done
        #### BEGIN emit-upstart-event
        case "$1" in
            start|restart|reload)
                initctl emit started-postgresql
            ;;
            stop)
                initctl emit stopped-postgresql
            ;;
        esac
        #### END emit-upstart-event
        exit ${EXIT:-0}
        ;;
    status)
        LS=`pg_lsclusters -h`
        # no clusters -> unknown status                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        [ -n "$LS" ] || exit 4
        echo "$LS" | awk 'BEGIN {rc=0} {if (match($4, "down")) rc=3; printf ("%s/%s (port %s): %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4)}; END {exit rc}'
        ;;
    force-reload)
        #### BEGIN emit-upstart-event
        initctl emit starting-postgresql
        #### END emit-upstart-event
        for v in $versions; do
            reload $v
    done
        #### BEGIN emit-upstart-event
        initctl emit started-postgresql
        #### END emit-upstart-event
    ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status} [version ..]"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

If you want to handle restarting with all the proper signals (by splitting restart into a stop and start commands) you can do:

```
case "$1" in
    restart)
        ### HANDLING restart as a stop event and then a start event.
        if [ -z "`pg_lsclusters -h`" ]; then
            log_warning_msg 'No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster"'
            exit 0
        fi
        initctl emit stopping-postgresql
        for v in $versions; do
            stop $v || EXIT=$?
        done
        initctl emit stopped-postgresql
        initctl emit starting-postgresql
        for v in $versions; do
            start $v || EXIT=$?
        done
        initctl emit started-postgresql
        ### END HANDLING restart separately
    start|stop|reload)
        if [ -z "`pg_lsclusters -h`" ]; then
            log_warning_msg 'No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster"'
            exit 0
        fi
        #### BEGIN emit-upstart-event
        case "$1" in
            start|reload)
                initctl emit starting-postgresql
            ;;
            stop)
                initctl emit stopping-postgresql
            ;;
        esac
        #### END emit-upstart-event
        for v in $versions; do
            $1 $v || EXIT=$?
        done
        #### BEGIN emit-upstart-event
        case "$1" in
            start|reload)
                initctl emit started-postgresql
            ;;
            stop)
                initctl emit stopped-postgresql
            ;;
        esac
        #### END emit-upstart-event
        exit ${EXIT:-0}
        ;;
    status)
        LS=`pg_lsclusters -h`
        # no clusters -> unknown status                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        [ -n "$LS" ] || exit 4
        echo "$LS" | awk 'BEGIN {rc=0} {if (match($4, "down")) rc=3; printf ("%s/%s (port %s): %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4)}; END {exit rc}'
        ;;
    force-reload)
        #### BEGIN emit-upstart-event
        initctl emit starting-postgresql
        #### END emit-upstart-event
        for v in $versions; do
            reload $v
    done
        #### BEGIN emit-upstart-event
        initctl emit started-postgresql
        #### END emit-upstart-event
    ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status} [version ..]"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the whole thing like this! If the postgres server is restarted, shouldn’t there be “stopping-postgresql” and “stopped-postgresql” events emitted before the restart? Otherwise, services that would be disrupted by a postgres restart might try to talk to the database while it’s restarting.

Comment: @bdesham - The problem with restart is the script runs `restart 9.2` as one command in between which both stops and starts postgres.  So sending emitting a  stopping / stopped / starting signal before hand isn't right -- ideally you'd emit a stopping, call stop, then emit stopped, then emit starting, and then call starting.  It wouldn't be too difficult to modify the script to do this.

Comment: @bdesham - Edit the answer to reflect this.  The signals are still possibly wrong for reload (only getting starting / started signals, which may not be the most appropriate way to handle).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote s a script in which I made a -system-update function, which stops openerp, updates the system by apt-get upgrade, then starts openerp, then restart web-client in case of version < 6.1. Problem is that it requires you use the script to update your server. I didn't use an alias.